# always point to other attribute's function

Tags: python, class, pygame

I´m working on improving my pythonic coding and want to know if there is a way to always point to an attribute's function in the same class (including "updating" its values)

the simplified code looks like this:

```
class xyz:
    def __init__(self, widht, height):
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
obj = xyz(42, 42)
obj.image = pygame.Surface((some_other_width, some_other_height))
# obj.rect would still be of size 42x42 and not the new values
```

since the image is varying in size, changing very often and my class has to have a attribute named rect with the size of the curent image is there maybe a magic method that could the work of the update_rect() function (tried playing around with self__getattribute()__ a bit but that didn´t work)

```
def update_rect(self):
    self.rect.width, self.rect.height = self.image.get_width(), self.image.get_height()
```

Comment: Make `rect` a read-only [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) that always returns `self.image.get_rect()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jonrsharpe suggested in a comment, you can use a property. But make `image` a property, not `rect`, like this:

```
import pygame

class xyz(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self._image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    @property
    def image(self):
        return self._image

    @image.setter
    def image(self, value):
        self._image = value
        self.rect = self._image.get_rect(topleft=self.rect.topleft)

obj = xyz(42, 42)
obj.rect.topleft = (300, 300)

print(obj.rect.width)   # prints 42
print(obj.rect.x)       # prints 300

obj.image = pygame.Surface((100, 100))

print(obj.rect.width)   # prints 100
print(obj.rect.x)       # prints 300
```

This way, you can also keep the position that is usually stored in the `rect` attribute.

Comment: perfect, thanks it worked with protected image, just wondering why setters with public attributes throw a recursion error... I´m off reading about oop im python it´s more complex than i thought :)

Comment: @Robin The code you posted in your answer leads to an overflow because inside the `image` setter you call `self.image = image`, and assigning something to `self.image` will call the setter again, thus calling `self.image = image` again, and so on. The trick is that assign something to a property no longer really assigns something; a method call is made. So if your think about `self.image = image` as `self.image(image)` you'll see that this is an infinite recursion loop.

Comment: would it be better if I changed all attributes to protected and access/change them with getters and setters like it is common in java? Or was it just necessary in this case to avoid an overflow?

Comment: @Robin In Java you would have the same problem if you would call `setFoo(...)` inside `setFoo(...)`. IMHO you should use properties only sparingly in Python.

Comment: Yeah never thought about that, since attributes in Java are/should be private most of the time anyways... never stumbled over that problem....  Well thats good I´ll just use them if neccesary cheers man.